# Can I "purchase" a free book from the Store without providing a credit card number?

Tags: google-play-store

There are a few books on Google Play that are free. Can I obtain said books without providing a credit card number?

Comment: I don't think so. You need a Google Wallet account and that needs at least one credit card. Your only other option is probably to have a gift card balance, but admittedly I've not tried that.

Comment: Give it a try maybe?

Comment: debit card also works. no need for bank accounts and even students can get one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like it depends on the book. From [Google Play support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2851613?hl=en):

> Downloading free music, TV shows, and certain free books and magazines is still considered a transaction, even when the price of the item is $0.00. If you don't have a credit card associated to your Google Wallet account or if you don't haven't set up a Google Wallet account, you'll be prompted to add a new payment method upon when downloading certain content from Google Play.

Answer (score 1):

Google has released an app called [Google Opinion Rewards](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.paidtasks). With this, users can get a couple cents at a time, which allows them to "purchase" these books now.

Comment: Can you download the app without a credit card?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yep, you can download free apps on the Play Store without a credit card.

Comment: How do you do that?  Do you just hit "skip" when they ask you for a credit card?

Comment: I was not sure about the working of the App, but I installed, registered and answered first dummy survey. After around half an hour I got actual survey, which credited 10/-. This can be used for test/free purchases.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot read them with out providing your credit card details.

You have to provide them or use Google Wallet.

Comment: Please don't use txtspk.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it used to be possible to register with a generated card number. You can get those for example here: http://www.darkcoding.net/credit-card-numbers/
See [How to get Google Music Without Credit Card for Free Music](http://thelegosoftware.wordpress.com/2012/03/27/how-to-get-google-music-without-credit-card-for-free-music/).

Unfortunately I am not able to register a generated card number any more. It seems that Google started to perform additional checks of the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, No you cannot.

A sad fact really, as many youngsters want to read through their phone and this limits many to do so.

Comment: What did this answer provide that the others don't?